# Remove border on left side of table when using multirow

Tags: tables

I am creating a table using the tabular environment. The first column of the data section begins with the `\multirow` command. I would like to remove the border on the left side of the first column, and remove the thicker vertical line on the right of the first column over rows 2-6. I have looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220575/remove-table-borders) answer, but I could not figure out how to translate the solution to the `multirow` context. I have also consulted a [multirow](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/multirow/multirow.pdf) help file but came up empty. I do not want to use the `booktabs` package because the journal where I will submit the article does not want authors to use extra packages. Here is the code for the table.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Statistics for the 1Hz bedload flux time series}\vspace{1ex}
\centering
\scalebox{0.75}{
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large{\textbf{Steady-state}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large{\textbf{Transient}}} \\
        \cline{3-6}
        & & t1910min & t4070min & t2150min & t4310min \\
        \hline 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total Time Series Duration (seconds)} & 14,396 & 14,245 & 4,582 & 4,529 \\
        \hline
        \multirow{7}{*}{Total Particle Count} &
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{4 mm} & 21,631 & 28,803 & 80,049 & 97,680 \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{}                     &
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{5.6 mm} & 11,423 & 18,043 & 38,782 & 47,241 \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{}                        &
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{8 mm} & 5,262 & 9,370 & 17,662 & 21,673  \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{}                        &
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{11.3 mm} & 3,303 & 5,710 & 9,630 & 11,626  \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{}                        &
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{16 mm} & 935 & 1,719 & 2,695 & 3,087  \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{}                        &
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{22.6 mm} & 92 & 278 & 410 & 568 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{}                        &
        \multicolumn{1}{ c| }{\textbf{Total}} & \textbf{42,646} & \textbf{63,923} & \textbf{149,228} & \textbf{181,875} \\   
        \hline
        \label{Table1}
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}
```

Here is the output of the minimal working example, using the \multirow package:

[image: Output of minimal working example]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: just delete all the `\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{` you don't want a multicolumn and the left `|` is making the left border in the first column and the double thickness in the second column.  Just use `c|c|cccc` as the array preamble.

Comment: please make your MWE a compete document loading all used packages so people can test it. Also never apply `\scalebox` to tables (if you do don't forget the `%` in `\scalebox{0.75}{%` but far better not to do  it

Comment: Thanks @David, and I will follow your instructions about the MWE and `\scalebox` in the future. I tried your suggestion and it did not quite work, but I may have implemented it incorrectly. But, your suggestions led to an output that is close to what I was after. I deleted the` \multicolumn` calls in each line that lists out data, but left these intervening `\multicolumn` calls: `\multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{}` . Removing the vertical lines from `|c|` removed all the vertical lines within the table. I left the array in the preamble as it was because changing it added vertical lines in weird ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this answer not solve directly your problem, it rather avoid it with removing all vertical lines in table:

[image]

(red lines  indicate text border)

since you not provide any information about your document, in *mwe* (minimal working example) is considered standard `article` document class. in preamble are loaded packages and defined commands, which enable to design showed table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- new
\newcommand{\B}{\bfseries}
\robustify\B

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\large\bfseries}
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
             mode=text,
             table-format=3.3,
             output-decimal-marker={,}}
\caption{Statistics for the 1Hz bedload flux time series}\vspace{1ex}
\label{Table1}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X r SSSS @{}}
    &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Steady-state}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Transient}} \\
    \cmidrule(r){3-4}
    \cmidrule(l){5-6}
    &   & {t1910min} & {t4070min} & {t2150min} & {t4310min} \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{TTSD (seconds):}
                    & 14,396 & 14,245 & 4,582 & 4,529 \\
    \midrule
\multirow{7}{=}{Total Particle Count}
    & \SI{4.0{mm}   &  21,631 &  28,803 &  80,049 &  97,680    \\
    & \SI{5.6}{mm}  &  11,423 &  18,043 &  38,782 &  47,241    \\
    & \SI{8.0}{mm}  &   5,262 &   9,370 &  17,662 &  21,673    \\
    & \SI{11.3}{mm} &   3,303 &   5,710 &   9,630 &  11,626    \\
    & \SI{16.0}{mm} & 935     &   1,719 &   2,695 &   3,087    \\
    & \SI{22.6}{mm} &  92     & 278     & 410     & 568        \\
    & \textbf{Total}
                    &\B 42,646 &\B 63,923 &\B 149,228 &\B 181,875 \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{TTSD: Total Time Series Duration }
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. I implemented the guts of your suggestion, but without the extra packages due to journal restrictions. Only using `\multirow` I can get a final output that is pretty close to yours. I also like your suggested us of the abbreviation TTSD.

Comment: @SurfProc, what journal it is, that not allow to use standard LaTeX packages? however. it is possible to write table with use `multirow` package only. just replace `S` columns with `c` or `r`, rules with `\hlines`, etc (as you probably did).

Comment: it is an EGU journal. They supply a .cls file with packages preloaded so copy editing and post production goes more smoothly - atleast  that is the story. Yes, you are correct - I can post the MWE to document if that is a standard thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am providing the following answer to follow-up on the excellent suggestions by @David and @Zarko. Here is a minimal working example (MWE) that addresses my questions, but slightly modifies the vertical lines within the table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Statistics for the 1Hz bedload flux time series}\vspace{1ex}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large{\textbf{Steady-state}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large{\textbf{Transient}}} \\
        \cline{3-6}
        & & t1910min & t4070min & t2150min & t4310min \\
        \hline 
        \multicolumn{2}{r}{TTSD (sec.)} & 14,396 & 14,245 & 4,582 & 4,529 \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{ r| }{\multirow{7}{*}{Total Particle Count}}        &
        4 mm & 21,631 & 28,803 & 80,049 & 97,680 \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ r| }{}                     &
        5.6 m & 11,423 & 18,043 & 38,782 & 47,241 \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ r| }{}                        &
        8 mm & 5,262 & 9,370 & 17,662 & 21,673  \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ r| }{}                        &
        11.3 mm & 3,303 & 5,710 & 9,630 & 11,626  \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ r| }{}                        &
        16 mm & 935 & 1,719 & 2,695 & 3,087  \\ 
        \multicolumn{1}{ r| }{}                        &
        22.6 mm & 92 & 278 & 410 & 568 \\ \cline{2-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{ r| }{}                        &
        \textbf{Total} & \textbf{42,646} & \textbf{63,923} & \textbf{149,228} & \textbf{181,875} \\ 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{l}{TTSD: Total Time Series Duration }
        \label{Table1}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The MWE provides the resulting table:

[image: MWE Table]

I think the Table by @Zarko looks nicer, but my MWE preserves the vertical line between the `\multirow` text and the data classes. However, I lost the vertical line between the data classes and the data matrix. I appreciate the help.

Comment: hm, this is new question :-). it will be better to ask it a such. On this way your problem will become visible to other site members too.  than they will have a chance to help you. temporary i'm busy with some other work ...

Comment: Okay, I see your point. My intention was to follow-up on the thread of our discussion around only using `\multirow` in the `tabular` environment vs. using the additional packages within your answer. I am pushing ahead with the table from my MWE and consider the help I got to have resolved my main issues. Thanks @Zarko